# Low-pass filtering using an AD8630

Tags: operational-amplifier, low-pass

I have a circuit that is used to amplify the incoming signal from a thermopile sensor.

The [AD8630](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad8628-8629-8630.pdf) op-amp is connected to resistors to have a gain of 1000 but I am confused about the capacitor. Is it there to provide low-pass filtering at 53 Hz? If it is, then what could be the reason to use such low-pass filtering?

The data sheet of AD8630 provides the following statement:

> If interstage ac coupling is used, as in Figure, low offset and
> drift prevent the output of the input amplifier from drifting close to
> saturation. The low input bias currents generate minimal errors
> from the output impedance of the sensor. As with pressure sensors,
> the very low amplifier drift with time and temperature eliminate
> additional errors once the temperature measurement is calibrated.
> The low 1/f noise improves SNR for dc measurements taken
> over periods often exceeding one-fifth of a second.

Can someone please break it down in easier words?

[image: Circuit]

Comment: "why AD8630 is used", Well, it has to be something. I'm sure there are many other OP amps that would work. About the capacitor, see here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/390986/non-inverting-op-amp-configuration-with-capacitor

Comment: That's not a lowpass, it's a *shelf*-lowpass (pole-zero). Because it's a non-inverting amplifier, so the transfer function is 1+feedback, which makes it of the form (s+a)/(s+b).

Answer (score 0):

Read the link posted by Klas-Kenny in comments.

In short, when you use a large feedback resistor such as 200K, the capacitance of the the inverting input causes the feedback signal to have some phase delay at high frequencies. Basically the *output is faster than the input* which causes a tendency for the output to oscillate uncontrolled at a certain high frequency.

To compensate, the capacitor provides a strong feedback path at high frequencies, so the output can be well regulated again. It has the side effect of forming a lowpass as you describe.

Another way to prevent oscillation would be a lower feedback resistor, but this choice can be limited when it results in unpractical resistor values.

The cited datasheet paragraph is unrelated